# How can I speed up Postgres performance of Django's User lookup query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

My Django site is starting to run sluggishly as the number of users scales up. New Relic tells me that the queries which consistently take the longest are the User lookup queries:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "account_emailaddress" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "account_emailaddress"."user_id") WHERE (UPPER("auth_user"."email"::text) = UPPER(%s) OR UPPER("account_emailaddress"."email"::text) = UPPER(%s) )
```

I have created indexes to hopefully speed up the above query:

```
CREATE INDEX auth_user_email_upper ON auth_user (UPPER(email));
CREATE INDEX account_emailaddress_email_upper ON account_emailaddress (UPPER(email));
```

Unfortunately, running the same `SELECT` query as an `EXPLAIN SELECT` indicates that Postgres is not using the indexes I've just created:

```
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Left Join  (cost=0.35..17926.55 rows=2039 width=83)
   Merge Cond: (auth_user.id = account_emailaddress.user_id)
   Filter: ((upper((auth_user.email)::text) = '%s'::text) OR (upper((account_emailaddress.email)::text) = '%s'::text))
   ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user  (cost=0.08..12637.91 rows=406463 width=83)
   ->  Index Scan using account_emailaddress_user_id on account_emailaddresss (cost=0.08..3868.99 rows=221167 width=26)
(5 rows)
```

I have found that without the `OR` conditional in my original query, and only 1 `WHERE` clause, the indexes get used. With both clauses, however, the indexes used support the `JOIN` rather than the scan.

Is there anything I can do to optimize this query?

*Edit:* Here is the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, as requested:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "account_emailaddress" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "account_emailaddress"."user_id") WHERE (UPPER("auth_user"."email"::text) = UPPER('REPLACED_EMAIL') OR UPPER("account_emailaddress"."email"::text) = UPPER('REPLACED_EMAIL') );
                                                                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Merge Left Join  (cost=0.26..18096.69 rows=2032 width=81) (actual time=22986.017..22986.017 rows=0 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (http://auth_user.id = account_emailaddress.user_id)
  Filter: ((upper((auth_user.email)::text) = 'REPLACED_EMAIL'::text) OR (upper((account_emailaddress.email)::text) = 'REPLACED_EMAIL'::text))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 402817
  ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user  (cost=0.08..12808.70 rows=405161 width=81) (actual time=0.017..6235.838 rows=402817 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using account_emailaddress_user_id on account_emailaddress  (cost=0.08..3868.99 rows=221167 width=26) (actual time=0.009..4034.638 rows=221189 loops=1)
Total runtime: 22997.255 ms
(7 rows)
```

*Edit 2:* The version is:

```
PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
```

Comment: what has this to do with django?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I guess it doesn't. This is a Postgres question. However, the query is being generated by Django, and so I thought other Django users might have encountered the same problem, and might be able to suggest approaches that have worked for them.

Comment: well...show us some django code. why aren't you solving this using DJango's QuerySet API?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the tags so that this is no longer classified as a Django question.

Comment: Please try `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` instead of `EXPLAIN`, and add the results to your question.

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version? `select version();`

Comment: 6 seconds to scan an index with 402817 rows seems rather slow. What kind of harddisk are you using? Might be interesting to run `explain (analyze, buffers, verbose)`. It could be that your indexes are bloated. Does it get better if you re-recreate the two indexes?

Comment: Actually, this has very much to do with Django, because that's more or less the generated SQL query for users signing in - at least this one is affected as well. Having several millions of users in a table, makes this query extremely slow - even with the fastest hardware! So, a solution would be very important for larger projects.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: No solution, but a workaround would be to query the account emails table first, getting only the user pks, then query the user table with Q objects (either: email matches OR the pk is in those returned by the original query). Normally I wouldn't recommend this, but in this case we know that the result set of the first query should be quite small, so the performance impact (either of loading the results into memory or of the extra `__in` query required) shouldn't be terrible.